# Two oncreate(bundle savedinstancestate) in the same activity?

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I'm very new to android development and have ran into an issue that I can't seem to get around or get my head around the resolution.

I'm trying to add a navigation drawer to an activity that has a bottom navigation bar in the java program. I've got the XML looking good and working but the below java is reporting the following error:

```
'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in 'MyApp'
```

which I understand and can see but I don't know how to resolve it - is it possible?

```
public class Dash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    Button signout;
    ChipNavigationBar chipNavigationBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        signout=findViewById(R.id.logout);
        signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Existing.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        chipNavigationBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_menu);
        chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.bottom_nav_menu, true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new NewsFragment()).commit();
        bottomMenu();
    }

    private void bottomMenu() {

        chipNavigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.bottom_nav_menu:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottom_nav_news:
                        fragment = new NewsFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottom_nav_profile:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override public void onBackPressed(){
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove one `OnCreate(....)`

Try Below Code:

```
public class Dash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    Button signout;
    ChipNavigationBar chipNavigationBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        signout=findViewById(R.id.logout);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Existing.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        chipNavigationBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_menu);
        chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.bottom_nav_menu, true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new NewsFragment()).commit();
        bottomMenu();
    }

    private void bottomMenu() {

        chipNavigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.bottom_nav_menu:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottom_nav_news:
                        fragment = new NewsFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.bottom_nav_profile:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        });

    }
 
    @Override public void onBackPressed(){
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much! I needed to add "Toolbar toolbar = null;" or I was getting a new error. Assume this is okay?

Comment: yes also remove `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();` from `bottomMenu()` method as you are replacing fragment inside onCreate

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much - removing this now allows this activity to be chosen from the bottom navigation without the app crashing.

Comment: So I have the activity working but the bottom navigation covers my drawer menu. Is it possible to either hide the bottom navigation when the drawer menu is opened or is it possibly to have the drawer menu cover the bottom navigation?

I've tried messing around with the elevation between the two but unfortunately it isn't as easy as that.

Comment: If This solved your Asked porblem please accept answer for future ref .